# Rails: making CGI::escape work in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried both of the following in a model:

`CGI.escape(default_url)`

`CGI::escape(default_url)`

and each time I get this error:

`undefined method 'encoding' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

Had to do `default_url.to_s` since for some cases it was getting set to `nil`

Answer (score 0):

check: [ActiveSupport#to_query](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3a04e370e4cc016bb7b59fe6bb704e4ca37d62f3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_query.rb#L8)

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_query.rb, line 8
def to_query(key)
  require 'cgi' unless defined?(CGI) && defined?(CGI::escape)
  "#{CGI.escape(key.to_param)}=#{CGI.escape(to_param.to_s)}"
end
```